# Centralizers of connected linear group and its Lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

If we have that $G$ is a connected linear group and $H<G$, where $H$ is also connected, with $\mathfrak{h}$ the lie algebra of $H$ and we define the centralizers of the elements in the following way:

$Z(H):=\{a\in G| aha^{-1}=h\forall h\in H\}$ and $Z(\mathfrak{h})=\{a\in G|ad(a)Y=Y\forall Y\in \mathfrak{h}\}$

I have a question which is asking me to show that these two are the same but I am unsure how to go about doing this, is there some property of the adjoint that I am not seeing here that may be useful?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is $H$ connected?

Comment: @EricO.Korman yes sorry I had not realised I has missed that out I will edit my question now thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these sorts of questions, you want to transition between Lie algebras and Lie groups using the exponential map.  The useful facts for this problem are:

1. $\exp(Ad_a Y) = a (\exp Y) a^{-1}$. This follows from $Ad_a$ being the derivative of conjugation and the naturality of $\exp$.
2. If $X \in \mathfrak g$ then $X \in \mathfrak h \subset\mathfrak g$ if and only if $\exp X \in H$.
3. A connected Lie group is generated by the image of the exponential map.

So for this problem, suppose first $a \in Z(H)$ and let $Y \in \mathfrak h$.  Then by 1.,
$$
\exp(Ad_a Y) = a \exp(Y) a^{-1} \in H
$$
so that $Ad_a Y \in \mathfrak h$ by 2.  Thus $a \in Z(\mathfrak h)$.

Conversely, suppose $a \in Z(\mathfrak h)$ and let $h \in H$.  Then since $H$ is connected, by 3. we can write $h = \exp(Y_1) \cdots \exp(Y_n)$ for $Y_j \in \mathfrak h$, giving us
$$
a h a^{-1} = a\exp(Y_1) \cdots \exp(Y_n)a^{-1} = (a \exp(Y_1) a^{-1})(a \exp(Y_2) a^{-1}) \cdots (a \exp(Y_n) a^{-1})
$$
which lies in $H$ since each $a \exp(Y_j) a^{-1} \in H$.  Thus $a \in Z(H)$.

Comment: "If ∈ then ∈⊂ if and only if exp∈." That sentence is not true. A counter-example is: $G=S^1$, $H=\{1\}$, $X=2 \pi i$. Then $\exp(X) = 1 \in H$, but $X \notin \mathfrak{h}=\{0\}$. Can you adapt the argument for the proof of $a \in Z(H) \Rightarrow a \in Z(\mathfrak{h})$?

Comment: @user505117 The OP was sloppy about the distinction between $Z(H)$ and $Z(\mathfrak h)$. The theorem should simply be: $Z_{\mathfrak g}(\mathfrak h)$ is the Lie algebra of $Z_G(H)=Z_G(\mathfrak h)$. And then for the nontrivial direction you take $X \in \mathfrak g$ such that $\exp(tX) \in Z_G(H)$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$. Then for fixed $t$ differentiate w.r.t. $h \in H$ to get $\exp(tX) \in Z_G(\mathfrak h)$, and then differentiate w.r.t. $t$ at $0$ to get $X \in Z_{\mathfrak g}(\mathfrak h)$.